# matplotlib: scatter plot not updating when data removed from dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a GUI that allows a user to create sets of points using shapes (e.g. a circle with center at X, Y and diameter D, with N points where X, Y, D, & N are inputs using entry boxes).

From the generated set of points, I make an entry into a treeview as well plot the points. The user can then select a treeview entry to highlight those points on the plot.

The data plots fine (I initialize a scatter plot with a blank data set and then add data to it each time the user generates an input). The problem I have is if a user deletes data (using a delete button in the GUI). The dictionary that the data is stored in (self.patterns) updates correctly, but for some reason the data isn't being removed from the plot.

I assumed clearing the dataset using

```
self.scat = self.ptrnFig.scatter([], [], c="b", marker="o", s=40)
```

in the plotAllPtrns() function would have given me an empty scatter (just like when I initialized the plot) and I could just re-add the remaining points in the dataset to the scatter, but that doesn't appear to work.

I also tried adding a

```
self.scat.remove()
```

line at the beginning of plotAllPtrns(), but then only the last set of user defined points is plotted, instead of all the ones remaining in the table.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")


class MainGUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Title')
        self.geometry('750x500')

        for i in range(9):
            self.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
            self.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        self.mydict = {}

        self.makeTable()
        self.initializePlot()
        self.makeWidgets()

    def makeWidgets(self):
        self.Labels = []
        self.Entries = []
        self.labText = [('X Location:'), ('Y Location:')]

        self.xGrid = 1
        self.yGrid = int(np.ceil(len(self.labText) / self.xGrid))
        i = 0
        for j in range(0, self.xGrid + 1, 2):
            for k in range(self.yGrid):
                if(i == len(self.labText)):
                    break
                else:
                    self.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.labText[i])
                    self.label.grid(column=j, row=k + 8, sticky='SW')
                    self.Labels.append(self.label)
                    self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
                    self.entry.insert(0, '0.0000')
                    self.entry.grid(column=j + 1, row=k + 8, sticky='NS')
                    self.Entries.append(self.entry)
                    i += 1

        self.addBtn = tk.Button(self, text='Add Entry', command=self.addEntry)
        self.addBtn.grid(column=self.xGrid + 1, row=self.yGrid + 9, sticky='NSEW')
        self.delBtn = tk.Button(self, text='Delete Entry', command=self.delEntry)
        self.delBtn.grid(column=self.xGrid, row=self.yGrid + 9, sticky='NSEW')

    def makeTable(self):
        tab_header = ['Pattern #', 'Description']
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=tab_header, height=5, show="headings")
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=5, sticky='NSEW')
        self.tree.heading(tab_header[0], text=tab_header[0].title())
        self.tree.heading(tab_header[1], text=tab_header[1].title())
        self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=("", "(new)"))
        self.tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.getPtrnTable)
        self.counter = 1

    def getPtrnTable(self, event):
        self.item = self.tree.identify_row(event.y)
        try:
            self.patNum = self.tree.item(self.item, 'values')[0]
        except IndexError:
            self.patNum = ''
        self.patternPlot()

    def addEntry(self):
        check = (len(self.tree.get_children()) == 1)
        self.description = "Location: " + self.Entries[0].get() + ", " + self.Entries[1].get()
        self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(self.counter, self.description))
        newEntry = [float(self.Entries[0].get()), float(self.Entries[1].get())]
        patKey = 'pattern_' + str(self.counter - 1)
        self.mydict[patKey] = newEntry
        if(check == True):
            self.points = np.array(newEntry, ndmin=2)
        else:
            self.points = np.vstack((self.points, newEntry))
        self.counter += 1
        self.scat.set_offsets(self.points)
        self.patNum = ""
        print("mydict: ", self.mydict)
        self.patternPlot()

    def delEntry(self):
        treeCnt = len(self.tree.get_children())
        patKey = 'pattern_' + str(int(self.patNum) - 1)
        del self.mydict[patKey]
        items = self.tree.get_children()
        for i in range(int(self.patNum), treeCnt - 1):
            old_key = 'pattern_' + str(i)
            new_key = 'pattern_' + str(i - 1)
            self.mydict[new_key] = self.mydict.pop(old_key)
            self.tree.set(items[i], 'Description', self.tree.item(items[i + 1], 'values')[1])
        self.tree.delete(items[-1])
        self.patNum = ""
        self.patternPlot()
        print("mydict: ", self.mydict)

    def initializePlot(self):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(1, 1), dpi=100)
        self.ptrnFig = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ptrnFig.axis([-5, 5, -5, 5])
        self.ptrnFig.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
        self.ptrnFig.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
        self.ptrnFig.grid(True)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=2, row=0, columnspan=6, rowspan=5, sticky='NSEW')
        self.scat = self.ptrnFig.scatter([], [], c="b", marker="o")
        self.scat2 = self.ptrnFig.scatter([], [], c="#ff5733", marker="o")  # Orange Color

    def plotAllPtrns(self):
        self.scat = self.ptrnFig.scatter([], [], c="b", marker="o", s=40)
        self.scat2.remove()
        self.scat2 = self.ptrnFig.scatter([], [], c="#ff5733", marker="o")  # Orange Color

        for k, v in self.mydict.items():
            x = self.mydict[k][0]
            y = self.mydict[k][1]
            bolt = np.array([x, y], ndmin=2)
            self.scat.set_offsets(bolt)

        self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def patternPlot(self):
        # All data deleted - reinitialize plot
        if(len(self.tree.get_children()) == 1):
            plt.close(self.fig)
            self.initializePtrnPlot()
        # No specific entry selected - plot everything
        elif(self.patNum == ""):
            self.plotAllPtrns()
        # Specific entry chosen - highlight selected entry
        else:
            self.scat2.remove()
            self.scat2 = self.ptrnFig.scatter([], [], c="#ff5733", marker="o")  # Orange Color

            patKey = 'pattern_' + str(int(self.patNum) - 1)
            x = self.mydict[patKey][0]
            y = self.mydict[patKey][1]
            bolt = np.array([x, y], ndmin=2)

            self.scat2.set_offsets(bolt)
            self.canvas.draw_idle()


def main():
    MainGUI().mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What am I missing here? I feel like clearing the scatter and refilling it (exactly like when I'm simply adding data) should work after removing a dataset.

UPDATE:
As requested I added a minimal working version of the code. Instead of creating patterns as described above it's just single points. Add points as desired, click on them in the table to highlight them on the plot, and use delete to remove them both from the table and the dictionary they are stored in. The plot doesn't update when a point is deleted and I can't figure out why.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the code to delete data?

Comment: The data is stored in a dictionary called self.patterns with they dictionary keys being pattern_X, where X is a number. When the user selects a patterns I'm simply deleting self.patterns['pattern_X'] from the dictionary and using the .pop() function to compress/renumber the remaining entries so that there are never any gaps in the numbering. I know the dictionary is updating correctly, which is why I don't see how clearing the scatter and repopulating (using the for k, v in self.patterns.items() call in plotAllPtrns()) doesn't work. If you really need the code I can add it.

Comment: I have the feeling this code is incomplete. So it's hard to understand what it is doing. Also one cannot find out why it's not working without running it. See [mcve]. (also mind "minimal", seems like a lot of the code is not needed for the problem in question.)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - I added the most minimal code I think I could to illustrate the point. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: In the absence of more code I see nothing that guaranties that when the program enters *delEntry* *self.patNum* is what you expect it to be.

Comment: You are correct. As you and @ImportanceOfBeingErnes pointed out, my reference to self.patNum is (was) quite weak. Also, I realized that I had a couple of missing lines, so the delEntry() function wasn't even calling the plotting routine. Even once that fixed, the issue persisted, but I was able to figure out why (I think). See my answer below. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I will simply provide the following code as is, which seems to solve the issue from the question. Attention though.. it will produce other errors in certain cases, because of `self.patNum` not consistently being defined and used. I can't fix those as well.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")


class MainGUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Title')
        self.geometry('750x500')

        for i in range(9):
            self.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
            self.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        self.mydict = {}
        self.patNum = ''

        self.makeTable()
        self.initializePlot()
        self.makeWidgets()

    def makeWidgets(self):
        self.Labels = []
        self.Entries = []
        self.labText = [('X Location:'), ('Y Location:')]

        self.xGrid = 1
        self.yGrid = int(np.ceil(len(self.labText) / self.xGrid))
        i = 0
        for j in range(0, self.xGrid + 1, 2):
            for k in range(self.yGrid):
                if(i == len(self.labText)):
                    break
                else:
                    self.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.labText[i])
                    self.label.grid(column=j, row=k + 8, sticky='SW')
                    self.Labels.append(self.label)
                    self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
                    self.entry.insert(0, '0.0000')
                    self.entry.grid(column=j + 1, row=k + 8, sticky='NS')
                    self.Entries.append(self.entry)
                    i += 1

        self.addBtn = tk.Button(self, text='Add Entry', command=self.addEntry)
        self.addBtn.grid(column=self.xGrid + 1, row=self.yGrid + 9, sticky='NSEW')
        self.delBtn = tk.Button(self, text='Delete Entry', command=self.delEntry)
        self.delBtn.grid(column=self.xGrid, row=self.yGrid + 9, sticky='NSEW')

    def makeTable(self):
        tab_header = ['Pattern #', 'Description']
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=tab_header, height=5, show="headings")
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=5, sticky='NSEW')
        self.tree.heading(tab_header[0], text=tab_header[0].title())
        self.tree.heading(tab_header[1], text=tab_header[1].title())
        self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=("", "(new)"))
        self.tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.getPtrnTable)
        self.counter = 1

    def getPtrnTable(self, event):
        self.item = self.tree.identify_row(event.y)
        try:
            self.patNum = self.tree.item(self.item, 'values')[0]
        except IndexError:
            self.patNum = ''
        self.patternPlot()

    def addEntry(self):
        check = (len(self.tree.get_children()) == 1)
        self.description = "Location: " + self.Entries[0].get() + ", " + self.Entries[1].get()
        self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(self.counter, self.description))
        newEntry = [float(self.Entries[0].get()), float(self.Entries[1].get())]
        patKey = 'pattern_' + str(self.counter - 1)
        self.mydict[patKey] = newEntry
        if(check == True):
            self.points = np.array(newEntry, ndmin=2)
        else:
            self.points = np.vstack((self.points, newEntry))
        self.counter += 1
        self.scat.set_offsets(self.points)
        self.patNum = ""
        print("mydict: ", self.mydict)
        self.patternPlot()

    def delEntry(self):
        treeCnt = len(self.tree.get_children())
        if self.patNum:
            patKey = 'pattern_' + str(int(self.patNum) - 1)
            del self.mydict[patKey]
            items = self.tree.get_children()
            for i in range(int(self.patNum), treeCnt - 1):
                old_key = 'pattern_' + str(i)
                new_key = 'pattern_' + str(i - 1)
                self.mydict[new_key] = self.mydict.pop(old_key)
                self.tree.set(items[i], 'Description', self.tree.item(items[i + 1], 'values')[1])
            self.tree.delete(items[-1])
            print("mydict: ", self.mydict)
            self.plotAllPtrns()

    def initializePlot(self):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(1, 1), dpi=100)
        self.ptrnFig = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ptrnFig.axis([-5, 5, -5, 5])
        self.ptrnFig.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
        self.ptrnFig.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
        self.ptrnFig.grid(True)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=2, row=0, columnspan=6, rowspan=5, sticky='NSEW')
        self.scat = self.ptrnFig.scatter([], [], c="b", marker="o")
        self.scat2 = self.ptrnFig.scatter([], [], c="#ff5733", marker="o")  # Orange Color

    def plotAllPtrns(self):
        print(self.mydict)
        self.scat.remove()
        self.scat = self.ptrnFig.scatter([], [], c="b", marker="o", s=40)
        self.scat2.remove()
        self.scat2 = self.ptrnFig.scatter([], [], c="#ff5733", marker="o")  # Orange Color

        xy = []
        for k, v in self.mydict.items():
            xy.append([self.mydict[k][0], self.mydict[k][1]])
        if xy:
            self.scat.set_offsets(xy)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def patternPlot(self):
        print(self.tree.get_children())
        # All data deleted - reinitialize plot
        if(len(self.tree.get_children()) == 1):
            print("One Child")
        # No specific entry selected - plot everything
        elif(self.patNum == ""):
            self.plotAllPtrns()
        # Specific entry chosen - highlight selected entry
        else:
            self.scat2.remove()
            self.scat2 = self.ptrnFig.scatter([], [], c="#ff5733", marker="o")  # Orange Color

            patKey = 'pattern_' + str(int(self.patNum) - 1)
            x = self.mydict[patKey][0]
            y = self.mydict[patKey][1]
            bolt = np.array([x, y], ndmin=2)

            self.scat2.set_offsets(bolt)
            self.canvas.draw_idle()


def main():
    MainGUI().mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: you are absolutely correct in my weak definition of self.patNum, though I don't think that caused my plotting issue. It may though as you pointed out cause some other issues, even once the plotting is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

As @Treizh and @ImportanceOfBeingErnes pointed out, I indeed had a weak reference to self.patNum. This was not causing the issue, but I have updated the full version of the code to improve this. I was also missing a call to the patternPlot() function within the delEntry() function, so that was corrected (though it did not fix the plotting issue).

What I believe to be the issue is how the set_offsets() is working when used in a loop. The original code loops through each entry in the dictionary and attempts add it to the dataset used for plotting. It seemed like something I can't explain was happening that allowed data removed from the dataset to remain (maybe a weak reference to the data stored in the scatter?). To fix this I stacked all the dictionary entries (since they are always all Nx2 arrays) and then used set_offsets() to add the entire dataset to the scatter at once. Corrected delEntry() and updated plotAllPtrns() functions are:

```
def delEntry(self):
    treeCnt = len(self.tree.get_children())
    patKey = 'pattern_' + str(int(self.patNum) - 1)
    del self.mydict[patKey]
    items = self.tree.get_children()
    for i in range(int(self.patNum), treeCnt - 1):
        old_key = 'pattern_' + str(i)
        new_key = 'pattern_' + str(i - 1)
        self.mydict[new_key] = self.mydict.pop(old_key)
        self.tree.set(items[i], 'Description', self.tree.item(items[i + 1], 'values')[1])
    self.tree.delete(items[-1])
    self.patNum = ""
    self.patternPlot()
    print("mydict: ", self.mydict)

def plotAllPtrns(self):
    self.scat.remove()
    self.scat = self.ptrnFig.scatter([], [], c="b", marker="o", s=40)
    self.scat2.remove()
    self.scat2 = self.ptrnFig.scatter([], [], c="#ff5733", marker="o")  # Orange Color

    patPlotData = np.vstack(([v for v in self.mydict.values()]))
    x = patPlotData[:, 0]
    y = patPlotData[:, 1]
    bolt = np.array([x, y], ndmin=2).T
    self.scat.set_offsets(bolt)

    self.canvas.draw_idle()
```

I'm sure I don't actually understand exactly why the old data remained in the scatter even if it was cleared (using scatter([ ],[ ])) or why adding all the data at once using set_offsets() appears to fix the issue, but it works.

If someone can explain I'd love to understand it better. Thanks.